# flip horizontal images in bulk

Tags: plugins, images, media-library, bulk

I'm using the WooCommerce plugin and I have a list of like 200+ products and I want to flip horizontally the images for every product.

If I will do this manually it will take me days probably to take them one by one.

I've looked for plugins which might help me do this automatically but no luck.

Is there any way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Photoshop - create action; batch process.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your best bet is to flip the images outside of Wordpress: download via FTP, flip, upload. You can batch flip images in OSX easily: http://osxdaily.com/2012/05/11/batch-rotate-a-group-of-images-with-preview-for-mac-os-x

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with CSS, using `transform: scaleX(-1);`, though applications will vary with your theme.

In one theme I was just experimenting with, all I had to add was this

```
.woocommerce #content div.product div.images img, 
.woocommerce div.product div.images img, 
.woocommerce-page #content div.product div.images img, 
.woocommerce-page div.product div.images img {
    transform: scaleX(-1);
}
```

That's just copying `img` styling from the theme's (DIVI) stylesheet as it turns up on Chrome inspector, and adding/adjusting the transform property. Though you used to have to apply all sorts of vendor variations, and, of course, special handling for Internet Explorer, to use CSS `transform`, I believe that the property is now generally supported.

If, however, your theme depends on displaying the images as CSS background images, then things may get a lot more complicated, and you might be better off altering the images themselves, perhaps following the method suggested by Adam Costanza or perhaps in some other way. That might also be the case if you need to have a bunch of images that have to remain un-flipped, and are unable to target the images by some common property - like a category class or some such.

In the latter case, writing a custom function that added a selector to images of the to-be-targeted-type might still be quicker, depending on your skills.